# Efficiently Filter Many-To-Many

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

In an app I'm writing I have users that may belong to any number of groups. There exists a has_many relationship through a corresponding group_membership model.

I am working on a reporting interface and would like to filter by groups, so I would like to return users who belong to ALL listed groups (even if they belong to other additional groups).

Currently, I repeatedly filter the set of users based on their membership to each group in turn, such that users are filtered out if they are not members of the current group.

```
  @users = @account.users.joins(:groups).where("groups.id in (?)",all_groups).pluck('users.id') #All user IDs
  positions_users = @account.users.joins(:groups).where("groups.id in (?)",positions).pluck('users.id') unless positions.empty?
  departments_users = @account.users.joins(:groups).where("groups.id in (?)",departments).pluck('users.id') unless departments.empty?     
  locations_users = @account.users.joins(:groups).where("groups.id in (?)",locations).pluck('users.id') unless locations.empty?     
  miscellaneous_users = @account.users.joins(:groups).where("groups.id in (?)",miscellaneous).pluck('users.id') unless miscellaneous.empty? 


  @users = @users.select {|x| positions_users.include? x } unless positions_users.nil? || positions_users.empty?
  @users = @users.select {|x| departments_users.include? x } unless departments_users.nil? || departments_users.empty?
  @users = @users.select {|x| locations_users.include? x } unless locations_users.nil? || locations_users.empty? 
  @users = @users.select {|x| miscellaneous_users.include? x } unless miscellaneous_users.nil? || miscellaneous_users.empty?
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you had a join model `UserGroup`, you can add the following scope:

```
class UserGroup
  scope :group_filter, lambda{|*groups|
    group_ids = groups.flatten.compact.uniq
    return self if group_ids.blank?
    where(:group_id => group_ids)
  }
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
filter = UserGroup.group_filter(positions, departments, locations, miscellaneous)
@users = @account.users.joins(:user_groups).merge(filter)
```

and your done!